# Rails deployment to Amazon EC2: Could not open library 'libcurl'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, libcurl

I've been following this railscast to deploy my rails app to Amazon EC2, via rubber: http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2

I got up to the point where I enter this in the terminal:

```
cap deploy:cold
```

Then I get the following error:

```
 ** [out :: web01.foo.com] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: web01.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: web01.foo.com] Could not open library 'libcurl': libcurl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
 ** [out :: web01.foo.com] Could not open library 'libcurl.so': libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 ** [out :: web01.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: web01.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: web01.foo.com] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 ** [out :: web01.foo.com] 
    command finished in 4322ms
failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /mnt/sample_app-production/releases/20120905210248 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on web01.foo.com
```

I assume the problem has to do with 'libcurl'. How can I install this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same kind of problem installing [graphiti](https://github.com/paperlesspost/graphiti) on a Ubuntu Lucid server.

I did not find the source of the error I encountered, but doing a simple symlink was a good enough workaround.

```
cd /usr/lib
ln -s libcurl.so.4 libcurl.so
```

Answer (score 0):

http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

???

Comment: I installed curl but I'm still getting the same error. Any other ideas?